# what is the major difference between ROS distributions

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ar-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I want to ask about what is the differences between different ROS distributions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276830/what-is-the-major-difference-between-ros-distributions/) by [ShehabAldeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31455/shehabaldeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2017-11-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As with new Ubuntu distributions, new ROS distributions contain new features, some old behaviours or APIs get deprecated etc.

All in all, this is not easy to answer.

The three biggest differences are IMHO:

1. the latest distribution is the one that is actively developed (or at least supported --> LTS distros)
2. ROS distributions are only packaged for specific OS distros (e.g. Kinetic for Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04, Lunar for Ubuntu 16.10 and 17.04, amongst others)
3. There has been one big change, the introduction of `catkin` between Fuerte and Groovy (if I am not mistaken).

More info [on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0